# Influence the apparent input resistance of a buck-boost converter

Tags: buck, boost

I want to power a buck-boost regulator (for simplification, preferrably one of the [integrated circuits from Linear Technology](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Buck-Boost_Regulators)) with a current-limited or high inner resistance power supply.

The power supply (a bicycle hub dynamo) is designed to deliver 500mA in a 12Ω load and to not deliver significantly more than 500mA current, even if the bicycle drives faster than what's required for the 3W output power. Increasing the load resistance to e.g. 24Ω, the current limitation in the hub dynamo still kicks in somewhere around 500mA, but with the higher load resistance, the available output power doubles to 6W.

Now, my question is: Using one of the mentioned buck-boost regulators, other ICs or in worst case even a proprietary design, is it possible to influence the apparent input resistance of the regulator, so that the regulator prefers to draw a low current at the highest possible voltage instead of a high current at a low voltage, even if both combinations of U/I on the input would suffice for the output power requirement?

Comment: Choose one with UVLO - under-voltage-lock-out - it won't begin working until a certain voltage is reached.

Comment: How would that solve the problem? If the immediate apparent load resistance is not high enough, the voltage would instantly drop below the undervoltage threshold.

Comment: It is definitely possible to alter the input resistance presented to the source. Solar charge controllers do this, for example, to maximize power. But I THINK that any DC-DC converter will do what you want. It will only draw as much power as it needs to drive the load at the regulated output voltage. This will cause the input voltage to climb, naturally, which will lead to even smaller dynamo current until the dynamo power out = load power / efficiency. You do need to consider what happens if the dyanamo power output cannot satisfy the load power.

Comment: @mkeith: Thanks for the feedback. Satisfying the load power is not necessarily an issue, since I am primarly just planning to charge a battery. If the available power decreases, the battery should ideally just charge slower. Looking into solar charge controllers might actually be a good idea, since the same principle applies there: 'store as much of the available power as possible, even if the power fluctuates'.